# Jquery ajax call works when applied breakpoint to ajax call else it show no result

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following ajax call to web service in asp.net.When I simply run the program, it won't work. In console, it shows

> 'http://mywebservice.asmx/add' in red color for a second and dissapear.

```
function btn_add1()
    {
        var aData = [];
        aData[0] = $("#tb_a").val();
        aData[1] = $("#tb_b").val();
        aData[2] = $("#tb_c").val();
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ aData: aData });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mywebservice.asmx/add",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
            cache:false,
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnErrorCall
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert("success");
            alert(response.d);
            console.log(response.d);
        }

        function OnErrorCall(response) {
            console.log(response.d);
        }

    }
```

But when I apply breakpoint and run the program it gives the desired result.
I am really confused and frustrated by this behavior.

Here's my webservice code

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public int add(List<string> aData)
{
    int cal = Convert.ToInt32(aData[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(aData[1]) + Convert.ToInt32(aData[2]);
    return cal;
}
```

Comment: It is hard to know the problem with only this information. Here are some tips for you to find out your problem: add a known log into the `OnErroCall` javascript function. Check whether this log is printed in the console. If it is, you know some error has occurred and you can use the javascript debuger of your browser to check out what is happening in this javascript portion. If not, add console prints to the `OnSuccess` method and execute the same logic explained above.

Comment: I have added the log on success and on failure method but none is printed.However if i apply the breakpoint the log on success function is printed.